# Unreliable POST with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, kendo-mobile

I need to send and receive some simple data with my mobile application. I do this using the jquery $.post function - but it seems to be very unstable.

Problem:
Often, like 1 out of 10 times, the POST is sent, but the callback function is never run. I know from the serverside that the POST is received and that data is returned - yet often there's nothing happening on the clientside.

```
$.post(url, { 'username': username, 'password': password },
function(data) {
    if (data.Message == "Ok") {
        alert("Logged in OK.");
    } else if (data.Message == "Error") {
        alert("Error. Check username and password.");
    } else {
        alert("An unknown error has occured.");
    }
});
```

The times when nothing happens on the client side (even though I see data has been sent to the server) - running the function again doesn't work. I have to reload the entire page and try again - and then everything works as normal.

The setup is jquery together with Kendo UI Mobile.

Is there another, more reliable way, to make this POST request using JavaScript?

Comment: Is the URL you're sending the request to on the same domain? Try setting up an `error` handler which you can use to interrogate the response and get the HTTP code returned, and an error message.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try. The URL is on a different domain - the app is on the users phone, whilst the url is external.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX requests could fail for any reason and you could work around this by giving the user the option to re-submit and on server-side you do whatever checking to avoid duplicates..

Or you can use timeouts, check this 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

- Timeouts for JSONP requests are available from v1.5

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has to be changed. i just tried and it worked

```
 $.post(url, { 'username': username, 'password': password },
    function(data) {
        if (data == "Ok") {
            alert("Logged in OK.");
        } else if (data == "Error") {
            alert("Error. Check username and password.");
        } else {
            alert("An unknown error has occured.");
        }
    });
```

Thank you.